# Autocompile in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating an Eclipse plugin for custom language similar to Java. Currently I made a compiler plugin (same as eclipse.jdt.core) and I created jar file from it. I also created custom nature for my Projects that will be written in that language. Is there a way to achieve building this project automatically like Java projects? I would like to somehow associate my compiler plugin to my type of project.

By adding this compiler plugin I achieved code completion, syntax highlighting and I can compile projects but I can't seem to find out the option to make it autocompile. By autocompile I mean whenever a file is changed it would recompile it to a .class file in bin directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.builders` extension point to define an incremental builder. The builder will be called when Eclipse thinks that a project needs to be built, for example when resources change. This is the JDT builder declaration:

```xml
<extension 
    point="org.eclipse.core.resources.builders" 
    id="javabuilder"
    name="%javaBuilderName">
    <builder>
        <run class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder">
        </run>
        <dynamicReference class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DynamicProjectReferences"/>
    </builder>
</extension>
```

The builder code extends `IncrementalProjectBuilder` and in outline looks like:

```java
public class BuilderExample extends IncrementalProjectBuilder
{
  IProject[] build(int kind, Map args, IProgressMonitor monitor)
        throws CoreException 
  {
     // add your build logic here
     return null;
  }

  protected void startupOnInitialize()
  {
     // add builder init logic here
  }

  protected void clean(IProgressMonitor monitor) 
  {
     // add builder clean logic here
  }
```

}

Each project has a list of builder associated with it (stored in the `.project` file). You can add the builder using the `IProjectDescription` `setBuildSpec` call. This is usually done when adding a nature to the project. Something like:

```java
String builderID = ... your builder id
IProject project = ... project

IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();

ICommand[] oldBuildSpec = description.getBuildSpec();

// TODO check not already present

ICommand newCommand = description.newCommand();
newCommand.setBuilderName(builderID);

// Add a API build spec after all existing builders
ICommand[] newCommands = new ICommand[length + 1];
System.arraycopy(oldBuildSpec, 0, newCommands, 0, length);
newCommands[length] = newCommand;

// Commit the spec change into the project
description.setBuildSpec(newCommands);
project.setDescription(description, null);
```

Also see [Incremental Builder](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_builders.htm) in Eclipse help.